# versioning ios application for appstore submission

Tags: ios, ios5, app-store, appstore-approval

Currently, am submitting one application to the apple store. is there any guidelines provided by the apple to version the ios application for app store submission?

Comment: what you want to know about versioning .
check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205098/app-store-version-numbers-changing-scheme-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any resources in developer.apple about this subject.

Please check this nice [article](http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-iphone-application-versioning-with-agvtool) for a good solution.